# PySys. pysysproject.xml: How to build <path> nodes relying on properties' values

Tags: python, unit-testing

In my **pysysproject.xml** some properties are defined that reference some paths in my project, in a similar way that those shown below:

```
...
<property name="path1" value="/dir1/dir2/dirA" /> 
<property name="path2" value="/dir1/dir2/dirB" /> 
<property name="path3" value="/dir1/dir2/dirC" /> 
...
```

At the end of my file, we also include some **<path>** nodes to provide the Python interpreter additional directories for searching for modules. That looks like similar to

```
<path value="./dir1/dir2/dirA/module1" relative="true"/>
<path value="./dir1/dir2/dirB/module2" relative="true"/>
<path value="./dir1/dir2/dirC/module3" relative="true"/>
```

where the base directories for **module1**, **module2** and **module3** correspond to the values provided for the **path1**, **path2** and **path3** properties respectively...

What I'd like to know if there is a way of using these properties when setting these paths, like:

```
<path value="./${path1}/module1" relative="true" />
<path value="./${path2}/module2" relative="true" />
<path value="./${path3}/module3" relative="true" />
```

I've tried this way before but, Unfortunately, it didn't work... The contents of the Python's **sys.path** object I get was

```
[ OTHER_DIRS, u'C:\\MSM\\tests\\${path1}\\Module1', u'C:\\MSM\\tests\\${path2}\\Module2', u'C:\\MSM\\tests\\${path3}\\Module3']
```

that shows that the properties were not replaced by their contents in the way we'd like (the following ouput is the "expected" one):

```
[ OTHER_DIRS, u'C:\\MSM\\tests\\dir1\\dir2\\dirA\\Module1', u'C:\\MSM\\tests\\dir1\\dir2\\dirB\\Module2', u'C:\\MSM\\\\dir1\\dir2\\dirC\\Module3']
```

Any feedback about that will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't supported at the moment. We do expand environment variables into the path element, but not previously defined properties as defined in the project file. I will add a feature request and implement in the next release.

Comment: Thank you, Moray, for your help!